# How to print the name of EKRecurrenceFrequency enum instead of its int value?

Tags: swift, enums

The EKRecurrenceFrequency is a built in enum so I have to use it as is.
So setting the freq to the enum value:

```
let freq = EKRecurrenceFrequency.daily
```

Then printing in the debugger:

```
(lldb) po "\(freq)"
"EKRecurrenceFrequency"

(lldb) po "\(freq.rawValue)"
"0"

(lldb) po String(describing: freq.rawValue)
"0"

(lldb) po String(describing: freq)
"EKRecurrenceFrequency"
```

None of the above prints the name of the enum: "daily".
Any idea how to do it?

Using Xcode 10.1, Swift 4.2.

Comment: `exp freq` gives `(EKRecurrenceFrequency) $R8 = daily`, is that enough?

Comment: Thanks Larme - that answers my question. Do you know how to get the "daily" value in the program itself - since expression is for lldb use.